# How can I change the value of Observable's member object's field?

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx, spartacus-storefront

There is Observable<> in ngOnInit().

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.products$ = this.someService.getMissingProducts();
  }
```

this.products$ is Observable<Product[]> type and Product has code(string type) member field.
I'd like to change all Product[]'s code values to new ones.

Sorry for this silly question. I'm not good at typescript & angular so I tried to find some solution but failed.

Is there any simple way?

Thanks in advance.

P.S. I added this code to my solution. thanks for Edward

```
this.products$ = this.someService.getMissingProducts().pipe(
    map( product => {
        return product;
    }),
    map((array:Product[]) => {
        return array.map((item:Product) => {
            blabla~
            return { ...item};
        });
    })
);
```

Comment: I'd like to better understand what you're trying to achieve. Do you want to come up with a "replacement product"? Or what's the reason to change the product code? Just changing the product code sounds not good tbh.

Comment: I'm Sorry for causing you confusion. Actually, the field name what I want to change was not code but other read only field . (I just wrote the field name 'code' as example)
The actual target field value came from api server, but there was no schedule for api server release. So I had to change the filed value in angular app.

Comment: understood, np. The right place to alter the field value might be in the adapters, you can read more about it at https://sap.github.io/spartacus-docs/connecting-to-other-systems/. But perhaps you don't need that complexity in your project. Converting the value according to the adapter system we offer means that you do it only once (upon loading) and it's stored in the internal store.

Comment: You're right. I should have done it at the adaptor.
I didn't understand spartacus structure well at that time.
Thank you for the advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the rxjs `map` operator to convert the value of an observable from one to another. [Link](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/map);

```
 ngOnInit() {
   this.products$ = this.someService.getMissingProducts().pipe(
      map( payload => {
        // Perform the operations you want.
        return NewValue;
      }
   );
 }
```

with the `pipe` operator you can use the `map` operator to apply custom logic to change the value of the observable to something else. want.

assuming you are using `async` subscription in the HTML template, you don't need to subscribe in the class. if you aren't using the async pipe in the template, be sure to unsubscribe in `OnDestroy`

Comment: Thank you. I resolved the matter with your hint.
I edited my question and added my solution for newbies like me.

Answer (score 1):

```
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';    

subscription: Subscription;
    
          ngOnInit() {
            this.products$ = this.someService.getMissingProducts();
            this.subscription = this.products$.subscribe((res: any) => {
                this.something = res;
            })
          }

          ngOnDestroy() {
            this.subscription.unsubscribe();
          }
```

A few notes:
This is the implementation made for the typescript file.
To get the value(s) from the observable, we have to subscribe to it.
When we subscribe, we store the subscription and unsubscribe on destroy (otherwise you will cause memory leaks in your application).

There is also the async pipe, in case you want to use the observable directly in your HTML template: https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe
For example, if your observable will output a string, we can use it like this (with the code from your example):

```
<span>Observable value is {{ productName$ | async }}</span>
```

Consuming the observable from the template is better when possible so we don't need to store the observable subscription, and remember to destroy it to prevent memory leaks.
The unsubscription will be handled automatically from Angular by using the async pipe.